# Forcing jQuery Mobile on Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm creating a mobile app using jQuery mobile version 1.3.0.

After the most recent update of Chrome for Android, the browser shows an un-styled version of the site. Basically it looks like the desktop version.

My question can take one of two answers: how do I force jQuery mobile styling on a desktop site? OR has anyone else experienced this issue and figured it out?

As a bit of background, my site is an ASP.net page with underlying C#. Also, I had to disable AJAX on the pages to fix some post-back issues.

Answer (score 0):

So this is strange...I fixed it though.

The issue was using https. That apparently blocked jQuery mobile...